# How to get ASP.NET Core Integration test working

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET Core 6.0 integration test working.

My code for the test is this:

```
public async Task TestMethod()
{
    var waf = new WebApplicationFactory<Persons.Program>();
    var _testServer = waf.Server;
    var _testClient = _testServer.CreateClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/Person/AddressXYZ");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _testClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

When creating `HttpRequestMessage`, I'm specifying an endpoint that doesn't exist (`/api/Person/AddressXYZ`), and yet the `HttpResponseMessage` shows a status of 200 OK.

I've looked at the console output and I see no errors or exceptions.
I put a breakpoint in `Persons.Program.Main()` and I see the breakpoint is being hit when I run the test.

Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong in the code above? I'm expecting to see some kind of error message when I send a request to an endpoint that doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the `response.Content`'s body content (e.g. `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`)? Do you have a default HTTP 404 handler set-up that's incorrectly setting the response-code to HTTP 200?

Comment: @Dai, Good thought about the default 404 handler - I don't have one specified.  response.Content is an empty string.

Comment: " response.Content is an empty string." Could you show your code so that we can test it and reproduce your problem?